# String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.[SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have already searched for answer saying the inserted value could be long or mismatch of datatype, due to that this type of error could come but this web app works fine on my local system but when I use it after publishing it to the web, this error shows up but all other web page insert queries work just fine

Error shows up on only this one page.

> String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +388
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +717
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4515
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +134
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +6557689
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +6560327
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +586
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +104
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +288
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +171
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) +303
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter) +485
>
> [UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
>
> System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter) +4502203
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) +583
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +218
>
> [DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +291
>   frm_addkarigar.btnadd_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1672
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +155
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804

And this is the c# code to insert the data

```
db_mytailorEntities _objdb = new db_mytailorEntities();
int count = _objdb.tbl_karigar.Where(obj => obj.name == txtname.Text).Count();

karigar.name = txtname.Text;
karigar.state = ddlstate.Text;
karigar.city = ddlcity.Text;
karigar.address = txtaddress.Text;
karigar.ph1 = txtph1.Text;
karigar.ph2 = txtph2.Text;
karigar.date_reg = DateTime.Now.ToString();
karigar.name = txtname.Text;

if (txtamntdue.Text == "")
    karigar.amount_due = 0;
else
    karigar.amount_due = int.Parse(txtamntdue.Text);

karigar.K_id = txtname.Text+"-"+(count+1);
karigar.foruser = Session\["userid"\].ToString().TrimEnd();

_objdb.tbl_karigar.Add(karigar);
_objdb.SaveChanges();

Response.Write("<script language>alert('Karigar added successful')</script>");][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

This error suggests that the data you're trying to write is too big for one of the columns.

Comment: check the data format that you are trying to insert/update

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32174152)

Answer (score 1):

This error suggests that the data you're trying to write is too big for one of the columns.  It works locally but not in your production environment, which could be a few things.  Is the schema the same on your local box as your production environment?  Do you know what data is being written that causes the error?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I can't leave comments on questions yet, just created this profile.

Comment: @S.Akbari No, I feel that this is a complete answer. It explains what the error is and some possible things to investigate for why it happens only in one enviorment. The only thing that he probibly should have pointed out is the OP should start looking in `frm_addkarigar.btnadd_Click` line 1672, he has a `SaveChanges()` call that is throwing the execption, whatever object is being saved is the one that has a field that is too long for the database.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, String or binary data would be truncated, but it was from a SQL table CRUD permissions being removed by a DBA.
So I'd look at the connection string, and the web site (IIS) Authentication / Impersonation settings, if nothing else work. It works from you local machine, but not from the web server. So a quick check is to enter your credential under IIS impersonation, or inside the web.config connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, the problem will be in the place where I did not expect an error. I forgot to make the id "identity", in order to it be incremental.
Yes, so simply.